# Application Farkas Lemma

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix and $C$ a $k \times n$ matrix. Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Show that exactly one of the following holds:

a) There exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax \leq b, Cx = d$ and $x \geq 0$

b) There exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^m, z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $y \geq 0,   y^TA + z^Tc \geq 0$ and $y^Tb + z^Td <0$

We should probably start by adding slack variables $s \geq 0$ such that $Ax + Is = b$ and move on from there but I am completely lost in how to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to reformulate (a) to use Farkas' lemma, as you write correctly. Adding $s \ge 0$ gives us 
$$ \begin{array}{rl} Ax + Is &= b\\ Cx + 0s &= d\end{array} $$
or 
$$\tag{$*_1$} \begin{pmatrix} A & I\\ C & 0\end{pmatrix} \binom xs = \binom bd, \quad \binom xs \ge 0 $$
By Farkas' lemma, either $(*_1)$ has a solution $(x,s) \in \mathbf R^{n+m}$ or 
$$ (y^t,z^t)\begin{pmatrix} A & I\\ C & 0\end{pmatrix} \ge 0, \quad (y^t, z^t)\binom bd < 0 \tag{$*_2$} $$
has. Writing $(*_2)$ in another form, we must have $$y^t A + z^t C \ge 0,\quad y \ge 0, \quad y^t b + z^t d <  0 $$
which is exactly your b).

Comment: Thank you! I missed that we could write $Cx = d$ as $Cx + 0s = d$. One small thing, in $(*1)$ I assume you multiply the first matrix by $\binom{x}{ s}$ and not $\binom{s}{x}$ right?

Comment: Right. Thanks, edited-